# How to know if my iOS contains pirated contents

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ipad, books

This is my first question here and my question may sounds novice but I am going to spend my vacation abroad so I would like to make sure that my iOS devices are pirated free content.

I may have copied some contents from friends such as ebooks, music, videos, etc.  The problem that I have tons of apps so I may use multiple book readers such as iBooks, Kindle, and many others. Same applies for music and videos.

Is there a way to check all of the contents on my devices using an app or at least a systematic way for check up.

PS: my devices are 256GB and all apps are original and downloaded from app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer but I doubt you will have an issue here. After all a pirated eBook looks rather the same as a bought one (same for other media).

Having said that the only way possible is to open each and every app and check the content stored there. If you want to be really thorough you also may want to check old mails etc.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I was looking for an app and a systematic way that someone has done similar thing before.  Checking all apps I have is a way but I am afraid that I may miss something out.  Another reason is to get rid of any pirated (or as considered as pirated) from my devices.

Comment: @mazen97 There is no other way. Apps can't access data of other apps due to app sandboxes on iOS, also there is no easy way to distinguish between pirated and legitamate content.